# Can I create a BIDS project in VS2008 with SQL 2005?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, bids

From what I can find online about using VS2008 to create a integration/reporting services project it appears I need to have SQL 2008.  Does anyone know of a work-around that would allow me to use VS2008 with SQL 2005?

Answer (score 1):

Installing SQL Server 2005 client/workstation tools should install BIDS 2005.

Answer (score 0):

Your license for SQL2008 should allow you to downgrade and use BIDS2005.  I've had VS2005 and VS2008 both installed on the same machine concurrently.