# how to run project created on SQL server BI Dev. Studio 2008 R2 on SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server

i created BI projects on SQL server 2008 R2 but am trying now to open it on SQL server 2005 as am working now on another machince , but it gives me an error that this .dtprojc is not supported by this version of visual studio ( 2005 )...
Is there any way to run this project using 2005 version ??

Answer (score 0):

No.

There is no "downgrade" option or feature. Sorry!

References:

- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlintegrationservices/thread/c28210b0-691c-45ca-9f0c-685b423e881f
- [Can I create a BIDS project in VS2008 with SQL 2005?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/139342/can-i-create-a-bids-project-in-vs2008-with-sql-2005)
- http://www.sqldev.org/sql-server-integration-services/converting-ssis-2008-to-ssis-2005-9379.shtml